# removing Grey color tap highlight in windows phone

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

how to remove grey color tap highlight in Windows Phone 7? there is problem with IE browser only

I have tried using  this meta Tag but this doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

This meta tag only works on ie10 and ie11 on windows phone.

```
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/>
```